# Changed postgres password, but can still access DB without password?

Tags: postgresql

PostgeSQL v13.3 on a Windows host.

I ultimately want to do this as part of automation, but want to do it manually first.

I get into my DB by...

```
$ psql -U postgres
postgres=# ALTER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'mypassword';
ALTER ROLE
postgres=# quit

$ psql -U postgres
postgres=#

...or...

$ psql -U postgres -h localhost
```

and am NOT prompted for p/w in either case. If I do...

```
$ psql -U postgres -W
Password: <enter wrong p/w>
postgres=#
```

so above prompts me for a p/w, but I can enter anything and it will let me in!

I read Stackoverflow posts about this. like changing the `pg_hba.conf` file form

```
local all all peer
```

to

```
local all all md5
```

But I do have this in my `pg_hba.conf` file

```
local all all trust
```

Even if I change the value from `trust` to `md5` and restart the service, it doesn't work.

what gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should've RTFM'ed the `pg_hba.conf` file. I changed everything from `trust` to `md5` and it's prompting me now.